# Symfony/Doctrine: How to make Doctrine working with Unix socket?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to connect to PostgreSQL using Unix socket. It's I think only one way to connect to database which is on host, but the application is in Docker (I follow the principle to not containerize not replicated database). I'm using Symfony 4 with latest Doctrine.

I made a test on raw PHP with PDO, and it works. I don't have idea how to enforce Doctrine to use unix socket.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=/var/run/postgresql;user=xxxx;dbname=zzzz;password=yyyy');
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, true);
var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());

$stmt = $dbh->query('SELECT 1 as dupa;');
$stmt->execute();

var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

And the result of it is as expected:

```
www-data@ef0f2269b69a:~/html$ php o.php 
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1]=>
  NULL
  [2]=>
  NULL
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["dupa"]=>
    int(1)
    [0]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
```

The problem is whatever I configure in Doctrine I get this:

```
In PDOConnection.php line 27:
                                                                        
  [PDOException (7)]                                                    
  SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused   
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting  
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?                                     
  could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address          
        Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting        
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried Doctrine's syntax, raw PDO syntax, do not have idea.
Is there a possibility that my pdo_pgsql does not have unix socket support compiled?

This is what I tried as database URL in Doctrine:

```
pdo-pgsql://yyyy:xxxxx@/var/run/postgresql:5432/zzzzz
pgsql:host=/var/run/postgresql;user=xxxx;dbname=zzzz;password=yyyy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After debugging Doctrine's driver I created a not-so-elegant solution, but nevertheless it is working, and can be improved upon.

I don't like accessing environment variable in the driver itself, but possibly this can be improved.

**doctrine.yaml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        #driver:   %database_driver%
        driver_class: App\Infrastructure\Common\Service\PostgreSQLDoctrineDriver
        host:     %database_host%
        port:     %database_port%
        dbname:   %database_name%
        user:     %database_user%
        password: %database_password%
        #charset:  UTF8

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        auto_mapping: true
```

**PostgreSQLDoctrineDriver.php**

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Infrastructure\Common\Service;

use Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver;
use \PDO;
use \PDOException;
use function defined;

/**
 * Driver that connects through pdo_pgsql
 *
 * Forked original PostgreSQL driver, extended to have a possibility to pass raw PDO DSN to be
 * able to connect via Unix socket
 */
class PostgreSQLDoctrineDriver extends Driver
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function connect(array $params, $username = null, $password = null, array $driverOptions = [])
    {
        try {
            $pdo = new PDOConnection(
                $_SERVER['POSTGRES_DB_PDO_DSN'] ?? '',
                $username,
                $password,
                $driverOptions
            );

            if (defined('PDO::PGSQL_ATTR_DISABLE_PREPARES')
                && (! isset($driverOptions[PDO::PGSQL_ATTR_DISABLE_PREPARES])
                    || $driverOptions[PDO::PGSQL_ATTR_DISABLE_PREPARES] === true
                )
            ) {
                $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::PGSQL_ATTR_DISABLE_PREPARES, true);
            }

            /* defining client_encoding via SET NAMES to avoid inconsistent DSN support
             * - the 'client_encoding' connection param only works with postgres >= 9.1
             * - passing client_encoding via the 'options' param breaks pgbouncer support
             */
            if (isset($params['charset'])) {
                $pdo->exec('SET NAMES \'' . $params['charset'] . '\'');
            }

            return $pdo;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            throw DBALException::driverException($this, $e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'pdo_pgsql';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put socket path as a host, for example:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        host: /var/pgsql_socket
```

Comment: I didn't try the YAML syntax, but the DATABASE_URL syntax didn't work with the host = socket path option (the doctrine was validating the host and telling that it is not a host)

Comment: Yup, unfortunately for postgresql and socket connection we are not able to use DATABASE_URL. We have to provide each parameter separately in config.

Answer (score 2):

You may configure the socket via the `unix_socket` configuration option which seems to be available since some time ago: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Comment: I have tried, it is not available for pdo_pgsql.

You can check there https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/2.9/reference/configuration.html that only mysql supports it.

Comment: Mhm, does changing the host to the socket path work? https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/3624

Comment: No. The Doctrine validates host and says it is invalid unfortunately. The validation is on other layer, not on the driver itself.

Comment: I was trying url like pdo-pgsql://user:password@/var/run/postgresql:5432/dbname it wasnt working. I will check again my doctrine version, maybe I could have something to upgrade if the guy from #3624 issue says it works for he. If the socket support was fixed/added in some new doctrine version, then the docs should say about this...

Comment: I use dbal v2.10.0 and orm v2.6.4. Setting path to unix socket in place of a hostname ends with exception with message 'Malformed parameter "url".'

I checked those versions and both are recent stable.

Mine solution with "PostgreSQLDoctrineDriver.php" works. I have just run all migrations on the database on local testing environment :)

Comment: the unix_socket configuration option is only supported by the mysql driver

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me.  I opened multiple new questions on this topic only for them to be promptly closed as a duplicate of this question (which really wasn't the same question as my question was more about peer authentication):  [How to make Symfony authenticate to PostgreSQL using peer authentication without a username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68521254/how-to-make-symfony-authenticate-to-postgresql-using-peer-authentication-without) and and [Using a unix socket for Postgresql connection using Symfony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68513369/using-a-unix-socket-for-postgresql-connection-using-symfony)  On mostly trial and error, found an undocumented but not horrible solution.

We know that both PHP and Doctrine is capable of connecting using a Unix socket and peer authentication because both of the following work.

```
$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=testing");

$pdo = EntityManager::create(['driver' => 'pdo_pgsql','dbname' => 'testing'], Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration([__DIR__."/../src"], true, null, null, false))->getConnection();
```

So, one might think the following `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` will work:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_pgsql
        dbname: testing
        server_version: 13
```

But not so lucky:

```
[2021-07-25T22:15:57.675268+00:00] console.CRITICAL: Error thrown while running command "doctrine:schema:validate". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied" {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException(code: 0): An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied at /var/www/software-requirements/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php:88)\n[previous exception] [object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Exception(code: 7): SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied at /var/www/software-requirements/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:18)\n[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 7): SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied at /var/www/software-requirements/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:39)","command":"doctrine:schema:validate","message":"An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied"} []
```

Then I looked at what was being given to `\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\__construct` and found that the native Doctrine approach left both `user` and `host` as `null` but Symfony was inappropriately setting them to `root` and `localhost` respectively.  The solution was to slightly modify `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` and set `user` and `host` to null.  While not shown, obviously you can and should define variables in `.env`.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_pgsql
        dbname: testing
        server_version: 13
        user: null
        host: null
```