# How to make Symfony authenticate to PostgreSQL using peer authentication without a username and password

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I have configured PHP to authenticate to PostgreSQL using [19.3.7. Peer Authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-methods.html) over a Unix socket and it works with native PHP as well as when using Doctrine without Symfony, but I am unable to get it to work when using Symfony.

PHP is set up using FPM and I have created a pool which listens to a given socket and is run by Linux user `testing`, and there is also a PostgreSQL user and database also named `testing`.

The following native PHP script returns results without errors so I know that PHP, FPM, and PostgreSQL is setup correctly to establish a connection using peer authentication without a PostgreSQL username or password.

```php
$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=testing");
$rs = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM company')->fetchAll();
```

The following script which uses Doctrine but not Symfony returns results without errors so I know that Doctrine is capable of establishing a connection using peer authentication without a PostgreSQL username or password.

```php
$pdo = EntityManager::create(['driver' => 'pdo_pgsql','dbname' => 'testing'], Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration([__DIR__."/../src"], true, null, null, false))->getConnection();
$rs = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM company')->fetchAll();
```

How can I make this same connection but with using Symfony?

I expected the following to work, however, it results in `An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_pgsql
        dbname: testing
        server_version: 13
```

No clues are provided to journalctl but monolog reports the following:

```
[2021-07-25T22:15:57.675268+00:00] console.CRITICAL: Error thrown while running command "doctrine:schema:validate". Message: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied" {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException(code: 0): An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied at /var/www/software-requirements/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php:88)\n[previous exception] [object] (Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDO\\Exception(code: 7): SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied at /var/www/software-requirements/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDO/Exception.php:18)\n[previous exception] [object] (PDOException(code: 7): SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied at /var/www/software-requirements/api/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:39)","command":"doctrine:schema:validate","message":"An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] fe_sendauth: no password supplied"} []
```

Comment: Does the server's log file tell you what pg_hba line the failed connection was trying to use?

Comment: @jjanes  Not much.  journalctl shows nothing and monolog shows the what I just added to my original post.  Appreciate your response.